# Why Angular js Service does not work?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I wrote script to test passing variables between controllers, so i define a service and declare variable on it `getContents`, then pass it to next controller `personController`, but something goes wrong, this is my script:

```
 <script>

    angular.module("app", []).service("personService", function () {
       var getContents = {};
    })
    .controller("personController", function ($http, $scope, personService) {

        $scope.GetContents = function () {
            $http.get("/Home/Get").success(function (data) {
                debugger;
                personService.getContents = data;
                $scope.Persons = data;
            });
        }

        $scope.Save = function () {

            $http.post("AddPerson",$scope.model).success(function (status) {
                debugger;
                console.log('status =', status);
                $scope.ShowForm = false;
                $scope.GetContent();
            });
        }

        $scope.AddPerson = function () {
            $scope.ShowForm = true;
            $scope.model = {};
        }
    });
</script>
```

what is wrong?

NOTE: when i remove the `Service`, the controller work properly and get data from `/Home/Get`.

Edit: this is my edit:

```
<script>

    angular.module("app", []).service("personService", function () {

        var Content = {};
        return {
            getContent: function () {
                return Content;
            },
            setContent: function (value) {
                Content = value;
            }
        };


    })

    .controller("personController", function ($http, $scope, personService) {

        $scope.GetContents = function () {
            debugger;
            $http.get("/Home/Get").success(function (data) {
                debugger;
                console.log("successData :", data); //console did not log         
                personService.setContent(data);
                console.log("ServiceData:",personService.getContent()) //console did not log too
                $scope.Persons = data;
            });
        }

        $scope.AddPerson = function () {
            $scope.ShowForm = true;
            $scope.model = {};
        }
    });

 </script>
```

and this is my html:(for more help)

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div class="container" ng-controller="personController" ng-init=" GetContent()">
    <div ng-show="!ShowForm">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Firstname</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="person in Persons">
                    <td>{{person.Name}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: separate your services and controllers and give them their own .js files for starters. This will make everything clearer and make debugging much easier

Comment: please use `console.log(data)` to check what you getting in success and after `personService.setContent(data)` add `console.log(personService.getContent())` to check value is set in service or not.

Comment: i edit my script to add console.log , but console i have nothing , as i said $http.get does not call!!

Comment: do you you are getting any error ?

Comment: NO, it is strange, i really confuse:((

Comment: Oh shit, i find what is wrong, its because of naming, i have  ng-init=" GetContent() ,, but in my controller i have  $scope.GetContents = ...... , so it will not call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to return service

**service**

```
angular.module("app", []).service("personService", function () {
    var content = {};

    var person = {
        setContent :function(item){
            content = item;
        }
        getContent : function(){
            return content;
        };
    };

    return person;
})
```

**Controller**

```
.controller("personController", function ($http, $scope, personService) {

    $scope.GetContents = function () {
        $http.get("/Home/Get").success(function (data) {
            debugger;
            personService.setContent(data); // set content to service..
            $scope.Persons = data;
        });
    }

    $scope.Save = function () {

        $http.post("AddPerson",$scope.model).success(function (status) {
            debugger;
            console.log('status =', status);
            $scope.ShowForm = false;
            personService.getContent(); // get content from service..
        });
    }

    $scope.AddPerson = function () {
        $scope.ShowForm = true;
        $scope.model = {};
    }
```

define personService.getContent() to $scope variable to display on view page.

```
$scope.content = personService.getContent();
```

Comment: Also useful, if you are interested in 2-way binding between your view and your service, assign your personService to a scope variable.

($scope.personService = personeService)

Then, you can bind to it in your view. (ng-model='personService.content')

Comment: @Alex Yes, I am only showing how to set/get record to/from service, we can use it in $scope to display in view. `$scope.content = personService.getContent()` ;) thanks

Comment: i did as you said, but when i set debugger in controller, but never reach to debugger and $http.Get never call!!

Comment: can you update your question and code what you had tried ?

Comment: Nice idea.. But can't we pass using QuerySring?

Comment: This is similar to get & set in C#?? Until we set new only it will contains old value.. am i correct?

Comment: I've 2 services, for dashborad.html is xcontroller and USA.html is yController. In this it will not work. Because both wil instantiate first time

Comment: when you select Country, set your Country record to service variable say `country` and when you want selected Country record, use get to get selected Country.

Comment: I did like this.. for x and y controller i've used common getsetService... working fine :)

Comment: @PrasadKanaparthi glad to help you sir :)

Comment: Please help this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548408/init-is-not-calling-for-second-time-onwards-in-angularjs