# init() is not calling for second time onwards in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, html

I've something like below. I am binding countries to a dropdown .

On dropdown change i've to display different views.

```
 $scope.countries = [{id : 1, name : 'USA1', pageName : 'USA'}, {id : 2, name : 'USA2', pageName : 'USA'},{id : 3, name : 'India3', pageName : 'India'}, {id : 4, name : 'India4', pageName : 'India'}];

 <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country as country.name for country in countries">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>
 </select>
```

-

```
<div  ng-include="'views/'+selectedCountry.pageName+'.html'"></div>
```

i've init() method in both usaController & indiaController.
Now,

1. If i select USA1 then usaController - init() - Calling
2. If i select India1 then indiaController - init() - Calling
3. If i select USA2 then init() - is not calling.       -- Problem

**Observation**: If select X1 country then X.html will load. If select X2 then X.html is not refreshing ( init() is not calling). If i select Y1 country then Y.html loads. Now if i select X1 or X2 it is loading properly.
Let say i selected X2 here.. working fine. again if i select X1 then same problem repeats.

My init() function in controller looks like below.

```
(function init() {
    getSomeThing();
})();
```

Any solution please?

Comment: I got the solution. Add some random number (Guid) as querystring to ng-include="'views/'+selectedCountry.pageName+'.html?random='+getrandom()".. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<div ng-include="'views/'+selectedCountry.name+'.html'" onload="getSomeThing()"></div>
```

Expression inside `onload` attribute should evaluate when a new partial is loaded.

[ngInclude documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: I got the solution. Add some random number (Guid) as querystring to ng-include="'views/'+selectedCountry.pageName+'.html?random='+getrandom()".. that's it. Some caching prob.